# Best way to position div next to this sliding sidebar?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-transforms

I have a sidebar that slides open. What would be the best way to position my content next to it so that the sidebar pushes (not overlaps) my content? Keep in mind that I plan to make the page responsive.

The .centercontent div represents my future content; I would like it positioned directly to the left of the sidebar.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZQOPav

```
<body>

<input type="checkbox" id="sidebartoggler" name=" " value="" />

<div class="page-wrap">

    <label for="sidebartoggler" class="toggle">☰</label>

    <div class="side-content">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>

  <div class="centercontent"></div>

    <div class="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Projects</li>
            <li>Clients</li>
            <li>Blog</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
body{
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}
.box{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;

    border:dotted 1px black;
    display:inline-block;}

.side-content{
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    background-color:pink;
    transition: .2s ease;
    height:800px;
    width:170px;
}

.toggle{
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:30px;
    color:black;
    transition: .2s ease;
    position:fixed;
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
    z-index:2;

}

.sidebar{
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    left: 0px;
    width:120px;
    padding:30px;
    background:#333;
    z-index:0;
}

li{
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    margin-bottom:16px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: atialiased;
    cursor: pointer;
}

li:hover{
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

#sidebartoggler{
    display:none;
}

#sidebartoggler:checked + .page-wrap .toggle{
    left: 200px;
}

#sidebartoggler:checked + .page-wrap .side-content{
    margin-left: 172px;
    padding-top:200px;
}

.centercontent{
      bottom:200px;
      border:dotted 3px black;
      margin-left:250px;
      height:900px;
      width:600px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your layout I'd use the exact same hidden checkbox trigger you're using for the side bar. I'd add a width and margin transition to the .centercontent to shrink/push it over as the sidebar moves in to take up more space.

Something like:

```
.centercontent{
  bottom:200px;
  border:dotted 3px black;
  margin-left:250px;
  height:900px;
  width:800px;
  transition: marign-left .2s ease, width: .2s ease; /* Transition margin and width */
}

#sidebartoggler:checked ~ .page-wrap .centercontent {
  margin-left: 422px; /* 250 + 172 */
  width: 628px; /* 800 - 172 */
}
```

If you want the content to not change width but to literally be pushed off the side so it's partially hidden off screen you can just leave out the width line.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!
Do you know how to prevent the centercontent from being pushed down?

The 200 top padding in the 'sidebartoggler' line is effecting it and I don't know why. I'm trying to get the padding to only effect the side-content.

Comment: .centercontent is being pushed down because it's a div and a sibling of the sidebar. By default divs want to fill the full width of the page and stack atop eachother. This can be fixed quick-and-dirty by telling sidebar to not behave like a div. Give **.side-content** the rule `float: left`. That will make it take as little space, pushed as far left, as possible.  It also allows it to sit atop .centercontent's margin. Then it fits snuggly in .centercontent's margin.